# How to inspect all ClassVar inside class?

Tags: python, python-typing, class-variables

I have a Python class like the below:

```py
from typing import ClassVar

class Foo:
    bar: ClassVar[int] = 1
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.spam: int = 2
```

How can I inspect this class `Foo` to get the `ClassVar`s and their values?

I am looking for something like `{"bar": 1}`, and need this to work for Python 3.8+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by inspecting the class' `__annotations__` dictionary.

```
from typing import ClassVar

class Foo:
    bar: ClassVar[int] = 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.spam: int = 2

for attr, cls in Foo.__annotations__.items():
    print(f'{attr=}, {cls=}, value={getattr(Foo, attr)}')
```

Output:

```
attr='bar', cls=typing.ClassVar[int], value=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Typing seems totally irrelevant here. In any case, to get the attributes of an object, you can always try to inspect the object's namespace. For a class object,

```
vars(Foo)
```

Would work. However, be aware, this will return *the literal namespace*, so if you want to modify this dict independent of the class, you need to create a copy. In this case, a simple shallow copy:

```
dict(vars(Foo))
```

Would suffice.